# C++ -> Visual Studio 2013 -> Windows Form -> Objects accessed through methods

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

Hello once again I am asking some experts for help. This time it is not about Linux commands but **Visual Studio 2013 Windows Form** in **C++**.

As always, details :

I have project with 2 forms, that's not really important.

Important things are :

I have 6 files : Windows.h, Windows.cpp, Game.h, Game.cpp, Test.h,Test.cpp

Including : Windows.cpp includes Windows.h, Windows.h includes Game.h, Game.h includes Test.h, Test.cpp includes Test.h as well.

Windows.h and Game.h are form declarations. This is where I need work to be done.

Windows. cpp is used as main, it executes whole project and do stuff.

Windows.h is Form for Menu, it just connects to Game.h Form and becomes hidden when Game appears.

**Game.h is Form with game. I need to create and operate on objects in methods included in Forms connected to Buttons.
Example : Click on one button creates one object class Test with variable int number = 1 and click one other button changes this variable to 2.
I can't access same object through methods, all I can do is create two same objects and operate on them but they are different beings declared in other method. Is there any solution to construct object which can be accessed through every Form's method ?**

Test.h

```
#pragma once
ref class Test
{
public:
    int nr;
    char *test;
    Test();
    Test(int n, char *t)
    {
        nr = n;
        test = t;
    }
};
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"


Test::Test()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I declared objects in class Game as variables what gave me access to those objects in Game's method.